# sometimes my sql connection keep saying "PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result"

Tags: php, mysqli

Actually, I connected to 3 databases in different server, but I got problem in mysqli_query.

sometimes it worked fluently without any error, but sometimes it showed "PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result"..
I don't know what happen, it ocurred sometimes.

here is my connection :
connection.php

```
  <?php
    $DatabaseName1 = "db_name1";
    $DbHostName1 = "host1";
    $DbUserName1 = "username";
    $DbPassWord1 = "password";

    $DatabaseName2q = "db_name2";
    $DbHostName2 = "host2";
    $DbUserName2 = "username2";
    $DbPassWord2 = "password2";

    $DatabaseName3q = "db_name3";
    $DbHostName3 = "host3";
    $DbUserName3 = "username3";
    $DbPassWord3 = "password3";


    $mysqli1 = mysqli_connect("$DbHostName1", "$DbUserName1", "$DbPassWord1", "$DatabaseName1");
    $mysqli2 = mysqli_connect("$DbHostName2", "$DbUserName2", "$DbPassWord2", "$DatabaseName2q");
    $mysqli3 = mysqli_connect("$DbHostName3", "$DbUserName3", "$DbPassWord3", "$DatabaseName3q");

    $server[1] = $mysqli1;
    $server[2] = $mysqli2;
    $server[3] = $mysqli3;

    $count_db = 3;

    if(!$mysqli1){
     echo "error to connect server 1st";
     die();
    }
    if(!$mysqli2){
     echo "error to connect server 2nd";
     die();
    }
    if(!$mysqli3){
     echo "error to connect server 3rd";
     die();
    }

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
?>
```

task1.php

```
<?php
include("connection.php")
    for($i=1;$i<=$count_db;$i++){
        $conn = $server[$i];
        $array = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `table`"));
        $task = $array["field"];
    }
?>
```

anyone guys can help?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
for($i=1;$i<=$count_db;$i++){
    $conn = $server[$i];
    $resultset = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `table`")
    if(!$resultset){
      //do something
         continue; //if you don't want to break it
    }
    $array = mysqli_fetch_array($resultset);
    $task = $array["field"];

}
```

Comment: If there were no resultset and I put "insert query" below $task, could it be inserted or not by using $conn?

Comment: it will not be inserted if there is no resultset that iteration will be skipped by for loop.

Comment: but I need to insert it.. is there another solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you want to insert the selected data or another data after running this query

Comment: I need to insert the array data..
but, it can't be inserted too because mysqli_query insert has got same error too.

Comment: see we are fetching a record from the database and if there is no record present in the database we are leaving everything below continue  keyword and starting with another iteration so because there is no data  to insert you can not perform insert query.

Comment: after the error occured, I must update or insert the data manually to database.

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do with 3 different databases ?